# Determine path dynamically in Silverlight 2

Tags: path, silverlight-2.0, clipping, pathgeometry

I have a border with rounded corners within a canvas and want to add a clipping region to the canvas so that anything I add is clipped to the region within the border. I know that I can set the Clip property of the canvas but as the canvas and object are sized dynamically rather than having sizes assigned in the XAML, I can't figure out how to calculate the path to use. Is there some way to derive a PathGeometry from a UIElement (the border in this case)? If not what is the best way to approach this? Here is the XAML for the test page I'm working with.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TimelinePrototype.Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
        <Button x:Name="cmdDraw" FontSize="18" Click="cmdDraw_Click" Content="Draw" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtDateRange" FontSize="18" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="TimelineCanvas" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                SizeChanged="TimelineCanvas_SizeChanged">
        <Border x:Name="TimelineBorder" 
                Background="LightGray" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                CornerRadius="15" 
                Margin="10"
                Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) and [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) properties

```
var height = TimelineCanvas.ActualHeight;
var width = TimelineCanvas.ActualWidth;
```

Comment: I had thought of using those but was wondering if there might be some other, more clever way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code, but would still be interested in any alternate methods.

```
RectangleGeometry clipRect = new RectangleGeometry();
clipRect.Rect = new Rect(TimelineBorder.Margin.Left, TimelineBorder.Margin.Top, TimelineCanvas.ActualWidth - (TimelineBorder.Margin.Left + TimelineBorder.Margin.Right), TimelineCanvas.ActualHeight - (TimelineBorder.Margin.Top + TimelineBorder.Margin.Bottom));
clipRect.RadiusX = TimelineBorder.CornerRadius.TopLeft;
clipRect.RadiusY = TimelineBorder.CornerRadius.TopLeft;
TimelineCanvas.Clip = clipRect;
```

Comment: I'd have to endorse that method; if only because I've done it that way dozens of times without seeing a nicer approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try [blacklight](http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight)

The blacklight toolpack has a rounded corner clipping tool and is free.